# Animating one element inside Angular 4 loop

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-animations

I am new to Angular 4, and I am trying to apply an animation over one element once there is click on it.

in my current configuration, once I click all of the elements inside the loop are running that animation

```
<div  *ngFor="let media of mediaContent ; let i = index">
   <div class="photo-wrapper">
       <img src="{{media.thumbnail}}" [@rotatedState]='state'>
   </div>
   <button (click)="rotate($event, i)">
</div>
```

AngularJS part

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-media',
templateUrl: './media.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./media.component.scss'],
animations: [
    trigger('rotatedState', [
        state('state0', style({ transform: 'rotate(0)' })),
        state('state1', style({ transform: 'rotate(-90deg)'})),
        state('state2', style({ transform: 'rotate(-180deg)' })),
        state('state3', style({ transform: 'rotate(90deg)' })),
        transition('state0 => state1', animate('400ms ease-out')),
        transition('state1 => state2', animate('400ms ease-in')),
        transition('state2 => state3', animate('400ms ease-in')),
        transition('state3 => state4', animate('400ms ease-in'))
    ])
]
})

rotateState = {
    1: 'state1',
    2: 'state2',
    3: 'state3',
    4: 'state4'
};
stateNum = 0;
state = 'state0';

rotate($event, i) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.stateNum = this.stateNum < 4 ? ++this.stateNum : 1;
    this.state = this.rotateState[this.stateNum];
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation keeps only one state for all the medias. Since the state is being shared the changes are reflected in all the media.

You need to have a separate component for each media, which would eventually contain separate state for each media. And hence changes in state of one media would not affect the other.

Please look into the [stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnjacq)

`app.component.html` needs to have the following template, where `media` is a new component that needs to be created:

```
<div  *ngFor="let media of mediaContent;">
  <media [media]="media"></media>
</div>
```

The new `media` component should now contain the following template:

```
<div>
   <div class="photo-wrapper">
       <!-- width and height are just for demo purposes -->
       <img width="100" height="100" src="{{media.thumbnail}}" [@rotatedState]='state'> 
   </div>
   <button (click)="rotate($event)">Click</button>
</div>
```

After this the relevant logic to rotate the media and keep its new state should be moved from `app.component.ts` to `media.component.ts`